# If I buy an unlocked sim-free HTC Desire HD can I still get Android updates OTA?

Tags: updates, htc-desire, ota-update

I currently have a HTC Desire with T-Mobile.
If I buy an unlocked HTC Desire HD (Sim-free) and pop in my current T-Mobile SIM will I get OTA updates for the Desire HD or the standard Desire that I have with T-Mobile?

If I won't be able to get OTA updates, will I have a manual update option from HTC direct when they release updates?

I've never bought a Sim-Free phone before so not sure how this works.

Comment: saying which country are you on would probably help

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, Android updates are released by the Google then the phone's manufacturer (e.g. HTC) writes updates for the drivers, and providers (e.g. T-Mobile) only help with the distributions. So you will at least be able to do manual updates as long as your phone manufacturers released the update.

However, this means getting update depends on your phone manufacturers support (I heard HTC is quite good on this). If, for example, your manufacturer decided not to support updating of your phone (e.g. Samsung has no plans for updating Spica to Froyo), then you probably won't be able to update using official ROM (although there is almost always a community update to non-official ROMs).

Answer (score 1):

I have a non-branded HTC Desire and I get OTA updates just fine. You will actually get the updates sooner because these updates are provided by HTC directly, which operators have to brand for their devices first before making them available.

I can't imagine this being any different for the Desire HD.

You'll also have more options for installing updates by hand, as described [here](http://vanderwijk.info/2010/8/21/upgrading-the-htc-desire-to-android-froyo-2-2-by-hand) for example (again, this is for Desire, not Desire HD)

Answer (score 0):

I received OTA update to 2.2 in the summer. I have a SIM-free HTC Desire for Russian market. I bought in April.

I see no obstacles why a SIM-free phone would not get an OTA update. Generally it should be released faster, because it comes from HTC. In case of branded phones, update comes from carriers. That may need additional time as carriers include their software into the update.